# Is it possible to create a blob triggered azure function with file name pattern?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am developing a blob triggered azure function. Following is the configuration of my "function.json" file:

```
{
  "disabled": false,
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "input/{name}",
      "connection": "BlobConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

My function is working fine. It is triggered for all files in "input" blob. Now I want to filter files by its naming pattern. For Example : I want to trigger my azure function for only those files which contains "~123~" in its name.

Is it possible to do with some change in "path" property of "function.json" file?
If yes, then what should be the value of the "path" property?
If not, please let me know if there is any other workaround possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`input/{prefix}~123~{suffix}` should work. In function method signature, instead of `name`, use `prefix` and `suffix` to get blob name if needed.

Comment: @Yash Unfortunately not, one blob trigger allows monitoring only one container.

Comment: @Yash, you can use eventgrid to achieve trigger on multiple containers

Comment: @Yash No, but you can have multiple functions that all call a private method that does the real work.