# How can I add regex in a variable value in azure function bindings file?

Tags: json, azure, binding, azure-functions

I have an azure function and I want to trigger it when a new blob is detected. Current bindings in `functions.json`:

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "cfimages/{name}.png", 
      "connection": "ImageStorageEndpoint"
    },
```

It works well and is triggered with "test_image.png"

Now, I want to trigger it with a a certain file name (with a certain suffix) and I wrote this:

```
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "cfimages/_?topview.png", 
      "connection": "ImageStorageEndpoint"
    },
```

I dont get an error but I cant trigger it using a file "test_topview.png". Can someone help me with the issue?

Azure trigger bindings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the above requirement You may need to Pass the file name path as below in your azure function binding.

***Example Code for trigger file name:-***

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "image",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "path": "sample-images/{filename}",//
      "direction": "in",
      "connection": "MyStorageConnection"
    },
```

For more information please refer the below links:

- ***MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION***:- [***TRIGGER FILE NAME WITH DIFFERENT TYPES***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns#trigger-file-name)
- ***SO THREAD*** :- [***Is it possible to create a blob triggered azure function with file name pattern?***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53833086/is-it-possible-to-create-a-blob-triggered-azure-function-with-file-name-pattern)